# Is there a widely accepted, or intelligent way, to do user privilege setting and mount with Docker?

Tags: docker, user-accounts

I am using Docker to set up the development system for the whole team using R/Python/...

My way is create seperate container for different develop language.

However, since there are 10 people working in this container, so the user rights is one important issue.

But I want to save the data in the host machine;
so there is a mount:

container:/home/user_a -> host:/home/user_a (real save place)

Or to host:/mnt/user_a

So that no matter which container you use, you share the same data and can smoothly work, no need to pass data from one container to another.

I can add mount even after container is created.

So Is there a way when I create a user_a and his default folder /home/user_a

It automatically get mounted to host's /home/user_a
And only the host'user_a can get access to container's user_a?

Currently, when I add a user_a in container;

I manually add a mount from host to container;

And in Rstudio or Jupyter, they use there container's priviledge to proceed.

If this is the best way? If there is any potential problem for this? And if I changed a file's rights in container's /home/user_a folder, will it automatically change the host's folder?